# Accessing outside variables from timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I want to time a bunch of statements. For example:

```
s = """\
for i in range (0,3):
    for j in range (0,4):
        if alpha_beta[i,j] == 0 and vect2[i] != 0.0 and alpha[j] == 1 :
            print(i,j)
            alpha_beta[i,j] = vect2[i]
"""
timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100)
```

But it throws error: `name 'alpha_beta' is not defined`.

Variables `alpha_beta`, `vect2` and `alpha` are defined earlier. I cannot include those in the timer, because that will include their initialization overheads too.

I am new to Python and an answer modifying my code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import them in `setup`:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt=s, setup='from __main__ import alpha_beta, vect2, alpha', number=100)
```

Starting from Python 3.5 [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) may also execute code in the provided `globals` namespace. Setting it to `globals()` will enable `stmt` to access names from your module's namespace:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100, globals=globals())
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to provide a function rather than a string. This way your code can easily access the globals in the context it was created.

That is, your code would become:

```
def f():
    for i in range (0,3):
        for j in range (0,4):
            if alpha_beta[i,j] == 0 and vect2[i] != 0.0 and alpha[j] == 1 :
                print(i,j)
                alpha_beta[i,j] = vect2[i]   

timeit.timeit(stmt=f, number=100)
```