# Using timeit to compare the execution time in milliseconds between different statements

Tags: python-3.x, timeit

I want to measure the execution times between several print statements which give the same result (after reading a book on python which states that using f-strings is more efficient than using str.format() and % placeholders). My python is v 3.8.8.

here is my example:

name = 'Kimberley'

f'Hello, {name}, how is your day?'  # method 1

'Hello, {0}, how is your day?'.format(name) # method 2

'Hello, %(who)s, how is your day?' % {'who': name} # method 3 which should be the slowest one.

so first I have tried this which does not work because 'name' is not defined within the function.

```
import timeit
name = 'Kimberley'
timeit.timeit(stmt= "f'Hello, {name}, how is your day?'")
```

then I have tried this, however it gives the similar results of 0:00:00.000038 for each of the methods.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta

# method 1
start = timer()

name = 'Kimberley'
f'Hello, {name}, how is your day?'

end = timer()
print(timedelta(seconds=end-start))


...
#method 3
start = timer()

name = 'Kimberley'
'Hello, %(who)s, how is your lamb?' % {'who': name} 

end = timer()
print(timedelta(seconds=end-start))
```

however, this is not right because the book says that method 1 , method 2  and method 3 take  about 0.06, 0.16 and 0.21 milliseconds to execute, respectively.

So I wonder how can I use timeit() to measure the execution times correctly?

Comment: Have you read the [`timeit` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)? It gives relevant examples right at the top.

Comment: "0.06, 0.16 and 0.21 milliseconds to execute" - On what? An 8086?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing outside variables from timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352852/accessing-outside-variables-from-timeit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default_timer` is not the best way to measure tiny pieces of code, since it can be easily affected by other system processes, and the time taken is so short it needs run multiple times to be significant.

Instead, use `timeit.timeit` as follows, specifying test-specific variables inside a `setup` block.

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """
name = "Kimberley"
"""

method1 = """f'Hello, {name}, how is your day?'"""
method2 = """'Hello, {0}, how is your day?'.format(name)"""
method3 = """'Hello, %(who)s, how is your lamb?' % {'who': name}"""
method4 = """Hello, %s, how is your lamb?' % (name,)"""

for method in (method1, method2, method3, method4):
    print(timeit(setup=setup, stmt=method))
# 0.0563660740153864
# 0.17292902698274702
# 0.18335944903083146
# 0.09785140998428687
```

Note of course that these times (ms) are the time for `timeit` to execute each statement 1000000 times.

I've also added in `method4` which is faster than `3` since it doesn't have to do the 'mapping' from `who` to `name`.

Comment: Updated with times

Comment: So that's less than 1 ms for a million executions?

Comment: Yes - it's much less accurate than an average, but you can add `number=1` to the `timeit` params to see the time taken.

Comment: Sigh. So the question says ~0.1 milliseconds per execution, you're saying ~0.1 nanoseconds, and in reality it's ~0.1 microseconds. Are you guys Americans? :-P

Comment: thank you very  much, match.  do you have any links to more examples of defining the setup parameter?

Comment: method4 = "'Hello, %s, how is your day?' % (name,) " is correct.

Comment: Have fixed this typo when copying over - thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered another way with  globals=globals() following the solution above.

```
setup = "name = 'Kimberley'"

method1 = "f'Hello, {name}, how is your day?'"
method2 = "'Hello, {0}, how is your day?'.format(name)"
method3 = "'Hello, %(who)s, how is your day?' % {'who': name}"
method4 = "'Hello, %s, how is your day?' % (name,)"

for method in (method1, method2, method3, method4):
    print(timeit(globals=globals(), stmt=method))
```